# Guild wars 2 server population

Tags: guild-wars-2

I notice that most of the servers say that it's high but does that mean online players are high in population or that includes the offline players that doesn't play anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just online players, as I saw servers switching from "full" to "high" during the headstart. I don't think that too many players switched servers during the first hours.